# Codeigniter: Correct way to filter and search tables

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, activerecord, filter

**problem**

I have tables of teachers, students and classes, this is what the students table looks like.

[image]

I need to be able to search through and filter the table to find the students. There will be about 100 students to sort through.

I have a MVP that works but I know it is a bad way of solving the problem.

**What I have tried**

The flow goes like this...

1. By default when someone lands on the list of students *all* students
   are displayed.
2. However when someone enters a search and clicks on the 'Go' the form
   is submitted back to the same page... where the values are caught in
   an if/else statement.
3. If the fields are set then a different method in the model is called, which takes two parameters, `$field` (the database column name to search by) and `$search` the string that we want to partially match.

Here is the search form

```
<form class="form-inline" action="<?php echo base_url() . 'admin/students'; ?>" method="post">
        <select class="form-control" name="field">
            <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Filter By</option>
            <option value="first_name">First Name</option>
            <option value="last_name">Last Name</option>
            <option value="email">Email Name</option>
        </select>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="Search...">
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="filter" value="Go">
    </form>
```

Which submits to the Students Controller

```
    public function index()
    {

        $filter = $this->input->post('filter');
        $field  = $this->input->post('field');
        $search = $this->input->post('search');

        if (isset($filter) && !empty($search)) {
            $this->load->model('students/Student_Model');
            $data['students'] = $this->Student_Model->getStudentsWhereLike($field, $search);
        } else {
            $this->load->model('students/Student_Model');
            $data['students'] = $this->Student_Model->getStudents();
        }

        $data['module']    = 'admin';
        $data['view_file'] = 'students/view';

        $this->load->module('templates');
        $this->templates->admin($data);
    }
```

Which calls the in the `getStudentsWhereLike()` method in the Student_Model

```
public function getStudentsWhereLike($field, $search)
    {

        $sql = "
            SELECT * FROM students
            WHERE $field LIKE '%$search%'
            ORDER BY `students`.`registered_at`
        ";

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result();
    }
```

**Question**

Is this the right way to approach the issue? I know that the `$this->db->query($sql)` method is open to SQL attacks so I will sanitize input, but I am interested if there is a better, more flexible, standardized approach to filtering/searching tables with Codeigniter.

Comment: Perhaps off-topic, but for small amounts of data like this I like to use DataTables jQuery plugin, the search/filter is quite good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Codeigniter's [active record](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html) instead:

```
public function getStudentsWhereLike($field, $search)
{
    $query = $this->db->like($field, $search)->orderBy('registered_at')->get('students');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Will this be able to partially match the values, for example if I enter 'joh' it will find john and johnny?

Comment: Yes, `$this->db->like` have 3 parameters, the third is optional and take values `before` (`%match`), `after` (`match%`) and `both` (`%match%`) and the default is `both`